# Как загрузить данные в реляционную базу данных на php pdo

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Есть 3 таблицы со связью 1 ко многим.

(Project)-> там находятся все проекты.

```
CREATE TABLE `project` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Нет описания',
  `image` text,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

(Tags)-> там находятся теги.

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

(P_tags)-> там находятся id проекта и id тега.

```
CREATE TABLE `p_tags` (
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
--
-- Индексы таблицы `project`
--
ALTER TABLE `project`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `p_tags`
--
ALTER TABLE `p_tags`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`,`tag_id`),
  ADD KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `tags`
--
ALTER TABLE `tags`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `project`
--
ALTER TABLE `project`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=75;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `tags`
--
ALTER TABLE `tags`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=12;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа сохраненных таблиц
--

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `p_tags`
--
ALTER TABLE `p_tags`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `p_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `project` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `p_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

Нужно вставить в базу данных новый проект с определёнными тегами.`
Для реализации я попробовал сделать такую схему

После этого, нужно сравнить id тега который мы вписали с id тега который находится в базе и уже на основе этих данный делать вставку в таблицу p_tags.

По отдельности циклы работают, как их соединить вместе я не знаю.

Если есть какой-то лёгкий способ это сделать, буду рад ему научится.

```
        //Берём макс число. В $idcount[0][0] находится число, которое будет являться id проекта
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(id) FROM project");
        $sth->execute();
        $idcount = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        // берём все теги (id,name)
        $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM tags');
        $sth->execute();
        $tags = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Делаем цикл, узнаём что у нас 11 тегов
        for ($i=0; $i < count($tags); $i++) { 
        echo $tags[$i]['id'].' | '.$tags[$i]['tag_name'].'<br>';
        }
        // Делаем цикл, узнаём что мы вписали 3 тега +
        $proj_tags = $_GET["tags"];
        $proj_tags = explode(",", $proj_tags);

        for ($i=0; $i < count($proj_tags); $i++) { 
        $proj_tags[$i];
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но я потратил 3 часа на форматирование кода и он попросту не давал мне отправить сообщение. Поэтому мне пришлось сделать так, уж извините за такое оформление.

Comment: Давайте разберемся по порядку. "нужно сравнить id тега который мы вписали"(с) Вы пока ничего никуда не вписали. Вы в параметре Get каким образом теги передаете id или названия тегов?

Comment: если не получается красиво оформить, вставьте, пожалуйста, код без оформления. его приведут в нормальный вид. для редактирования нажмите [edit].

Comment: @KordDEM, извиняюсь, нужно было в самом начале уточнить. В параметр $_GET передаются значения через запрос: сайт.ру/script.php?tags=тег,тег,тег...

Comment: @SniffRx, "?tags=тег,тег,тег" это tag_name?

Comment: "?tags=тег,тег,тег" это $proj_tags
"tag_name" это колонка из таблицы tags

Comment: теги заведомо существуют, проверять их наличие не нужно?

Comment: @Ипатьев, попробую поиграть в Вангу)) Если нужно, то в любом случае select выдаст pid, null, и думаю в таблице P_tags стоит условие not null на оба столбца)

Comment: Извиняюсь что не выложил самих таблиц в самом начале.

Comment: Кстати, а нельзя сразу id тегов передавать с клиента? Зачем имена передавать-то? или надо все-таки проверять наличие и добавлять новые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном коде три крупных ошибки, причем очень распространённых, так что будет полезно их рассмотреть.

- Первая и самая главная, "следующий id" **никогда** не получают заранее. Это приведёт к ошибкам и порче данных. id ВСЕГДА получают только после того как строка была добавлена в БД.
- Вторая - данные **никогда** не выгружают из базы целиком, если надо проверить только несколько строк. Надо составить запрос, который запрашивает только конкретные строки
- Третья - очень желательно добавить **транзакцию**, чтобы в БД е болтались ошметки данных, не привязанных ни к какому проекту.

Соответственно, и пишем код, который помогает избежать всех этих ошибок

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();

// сначала добавляем проект
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into project(поля) values(маркеры)");
$stmt->execute([данные]);
$pid = $pdo->lastInsertId(); // Получили id нового проекта

//ищем id тегов
$proj_tags = explode(",", $_GET["tags"]);
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($proj_tags) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag_name IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($proj_tags);
$tag_ids = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);// получаем id тегов в массив

// Добавляем теги к проекту
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into P_tags(pid, tid) VALUES (:pid, :tid)");
$stmt->bindParam(':pid', $pid);
$stmt->bindParam(':tid', $tid);
foreach($tag_ids as $tid){
    $stmt->execute();
}
$pdo->commit();
```

Comment: bindParam c tid внесите в цикл) А так не особо понял зачем вам отдельный запрос да еще с in на борту)

Comment: Внести в цикл? Зачем? Запрос для id подправил, там была опечатка. теперь будет понятнее

Comment: Дак $tid это элемент $tag_ids на конкретном проходе. У него банально нет значения при первом выполнении. И в дальнейшем оно не переприсваивается же

Comment: tag_name = :tname в запросе и bindParam(':tid', $tid); в параметрах.

Comment: А, тьфу, разглядел. Ну да, без предварительного запроса тоже можно. по поводу bindParam читаем, как он работает https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Ну как-то так мб?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into project() values()");
$stmt->execute();
$pid = $pdo->lastInsertId(); // Получили id нового проекта

$proj_tags = explode(",", $_GET["tags"]);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into P_tags(pid, tid) select :pid, tag_id from tags where tag_name = :tname");
for($i=0; $i<count($proj_tags); $i++){
    $stmt->bindParam(':pid', $pid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tname', $proj_tags[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Само по себе неплохо, но решает проблемы автора примерно на одну треть

Comment: Что я упустил?)

Comment: Да, действительно, так проще. Транзакцию добавить, и будет совсем хорошо